# How to perform atomistic spin dynamics (ASD) Ab Initio Molecular Dynamics (AIMD) using VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, molecular-dynamics, aimd

I have tried normal AIMD simulation using VASP for Non magnetic materials. Now, I am interested to perform the molecular dynamics simulations for the finite temperature for Magnetic materials to understand the evaluation of atomic positions with respect to magnetic degrees of freedom and temperature.

For this case, how may I write the INCAR?

Comment: +1 Welcome to our forum!